Aborting snakemake install process when using a post deploy script
I am using a snakemake post deploy script to install additional software and check for requirements. The script contains following lines
if [ -z "$CPLEX_PATH" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: CPLEX_PATH is not set. Exiting."
    echo "Please set the cplex path to your cplex installation <your path>/ibm" 
    exit 1
fi

so the script exits with 1 when the env variable is not set.
My problem is now that the pipeline just continues running and dies in a later step because the required software is not installed. Is there any way to abort the pipeline from the post deploy script?
Thank you for your time
Pipeline to immediately stop when the post deploy script does not exit with 0
